# C++ compile time ternary conditional

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, conditional-operator

Please, help me to figure out syntax of compile time ternary conditional in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main(void)
{
 //const auto y = constexpr(std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(nullptr)>) ? 777 : 888.8;
 const auto y = constexpr(std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(nullptr)> ? 777 : 888.8);
 std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
}
```

Both of the options above give me `error: expected primary-expression before ‘constexpr’` (gcc-11.2.0; compiled with `g++ -std=c++17`).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can’t use `constexpr` like that. What the diagnostic means is “_I expected to find an **expression** but found_ ‘constexpr’ _instead_”

Comment: Ah, thank you! `constexpr auto y = std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(nullptr)> ? 777 : 888.8;` is the way go to :-)

Comment: :O)   glad to be of service

Comment: @S.V, That makes `y` always a `const double`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Well, the real use case is more complicated, but that is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although one solution is provided while I program it, I suggest other solution:
making your consteval tenary function template, As it can handle different type in it.

```
template<bool T,auto A, auto B>
consteval auto tenary() {
    if constexpr (T) {
        return A;
    }
    else {
        return B;
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main(void)
{
    const auto y = tenary<std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(nullptr)>,777,888.8>();
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use `-std=c++20` for my current project, but it works! :)

Comment: @S.V Then, you can use it by substituting `consteval` to `constexpr`!

Comment: I wish, something like that would work: `constexpr std::nullptr_t x = nullptr; constexpr auto y = std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(x)> ? 777 : *x;` Why is compiler trying to dereference a pointer in the expression part, which has to be rejected at compile time? :(

Comment: @S.V It is rejected in my VC compiler with conformance mode as C++17. maybe dereferencing `constexpr` `nullptr_t` creates undefined behavior.

Comment: In my above example, since `std::is_null_pointer_v<decltype(x)>` is true, dereferencing of `x` will never happen and y will always be equal `777`.

Comment: @S.V Well, as my knowledge about C++ standard is yet limited, I am not able to answer that... sorry!

Comment: @S.V: Even if branch is not taken, code should be valid, and `*nullptr` is deleted.